Custom info window adapter not loading images on first time in google map
I have google map in my application, and showing multiple markers on map. On tapping on markers custom info window is showing.
In custom info window I have multiple images to show and one recycler view. In that recycler view images are also showing.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_info_window"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_240sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_10sdp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_restaurant"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
       
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_restaurant_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="8"
                android:fontFamily="@font/hellix_semi_bold"
                android:text="@string/hearts_as_one_cafe"
                android:textColor="@color/color222222_constant"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_restaurant_background"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@color/colorFFE7F1" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_restaurant_type"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_cafe" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_restaurant_type"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/hellix_medium"
                    android:text="@string/cafe"
                    android:textColor="@color/color333333_constant"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:ems="16"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:id="@+id/tv_restaurant_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/hellix_regular"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                android:textColor="@color/color666666_constant"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/rv_interested_territiers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_interested_territiers_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/hellix_semi_bold"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/color333333_constant"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                <!--  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                      android:fontFamily="@font/hellix_medium"
                      android:text="@string/interested_territiers"
                      android:textColor="@color/color333333"
                      android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />-->

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_make_booking"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color186181"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/hellix_semi_bold"
                        android:text="@string/make_a_booking"
                        android:textColor="@color/white_constant"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_register_interest"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorEE2376"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_interest"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/hellix_semi_bold"
                        android:text="@string/register_interest"
                        android:textColor="@color/white_constant"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

CustomInfoWindowAdapter
class CustomInfoWindowAdapter(
    private val activity: Activity,
    private val mRegisteredVenuesDataHome: HomeResponseModel.RegisteredVenuesDataHome.VenuesHome?,
    private val click: Click
) : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private lateinit var dialogRestaurantBinding: DialogRestaurantBinding

    init {
        initializeDialogBinding()
    }

    private fun initializeDialogBinding() {
        dialogRestaurantBinding =
            DialogRestaurantBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(activity), null, false)


        val gradientDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            activity,
            R.drawable.white_info_window_background_with_no_border
        ) as GradientDrawable

        val bitmap = drawableToBitmap(gradientDrawable, 240)

        val roundedBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 20)

        dialogRestaurantBinding.rlInfoWindow.background =
            BitmapDrawable(dialogRestaurantBinding.root.resources, roundedBitmap)

        dialogRestaurantBinding.tvRestaurantName.text =
            if (Utils.isNotNull(mRegisteredVenuesDataHome!!.name)) {
                mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.name
            } else {
                ""
            }

        Glide.with(activity)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.image)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Bitmap> {

                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Bitmap>,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Bitmap,
                    model: Any,
                    target: Target<Bitmap>?,
                    dataSource: DataSource,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    resource.let {
                        val roundedBitmapImage =
                            getRoundedCornerBitmap(it, 15)
                        dialogRestaurantBinding.ivRestaurant.setImageBitmap(roundedBitmapImage)
                    }
                    return true
                }
            })
            .into(dialogRestaurantBinding.ivRestaurant)

        if (mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.category?.image != null && Utils.isNotNull(
                mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.category.image
            )
        ) {
            Glide.with(activity)
                .load(mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.category.image)
                .apply(
                    RequestOptions()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                )
                .into(dialogRestaurantBinding.ivRestaurantType)
        } else {
            dialogRestaurantBinding.ivRestaurantType.setImageDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    activity, R.mipmap.ic_launcher
                )
            )
        }

        dialogRestaurantBinding.tvRestaurantType.text =
            if (Utils.isNotNull(mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.category!!.name)) {
                mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.category.name
            } else {
                ""
            }

        dialogRestaurantBinding.tvRestaurantDescription.text =
            if (Utils.isNotNull(mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.description)) {
                mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.description
            } else {
                ""
            }

        if (mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.checkVenueRegisteredOrNot != null) {
            if (mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.checkVenueRegisteredOrNot == 1) {
                dialogRestaurantBinding.cvRegisterInterest.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.registered_background_with_no_border)
                dialogRestaurantBinding.tvInterest.text =
                    activity.getString(R.string.registered_title)
                dialogRestaurantBinding.tvInterest.setTextColor(
                    activity.getColor(R.color.color222222_constant)
                )
            } else {
                dialogRestaurantBinding.cvRegisterInterest.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.register_interest_background_with_no_border)
                dialogRestaurantBinding.tvInterest.text =
                    activity.getString(R.string.register_interest)
                dialogRestaurantBinding.tvInterest.setTextColor(
                    activity.getColor(R.color.white_constant)
                )
            }
        }

        if (mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.territiers!!.isNotEmpty()) {
            dialogRestaurantBinding.rvInterestedTerritiers.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            dialogRestaurantBinding.rvInterestedTerritiers.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            val interestedTerriTiersAdapter = InterestedTerritiersAdapter(
                activity,
                mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.territiers,
                object : Click {
                    override fun onClick(position: Int, `object`: Any, value: String) {

                    }
                }
            )
            dialogRestaurantBinding.rvInterestedTerritiers.adapter = interestedTerriTiersAdapter
        } else {
            dialogRestaurantBinding.rvInterestedTerritiers.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        if (mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.interestedTerritiers != null && Utils.isNotNull(
                mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.interestedTerritiers
            )
        ) {
            dialogRestaurantBinding.tvInterestedTerritiersCount.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            dialogRestaurantBinding.tvInterestedTerritiersCount.text =
                mRegisteredVenuesDataHome.interestedTerritiers.toString()
        } else {
            dialogRestaurantBinding.tvInterestedTerritiersCount.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun getInfoContents(p0: Marker): View {
        return dialogRestaurantBinding.root
    }

    override fun getInfoWindow(p0: Marker): View {
        if (!::dialogRestaurantBinding.isInitialized) {
            initializeDialogBinding()

        }

        dialogRestaurantBinding.cvRegisterInterest.setOnClickListener {
            click.onClick(2, " ", " ")
        }

        return dialogRestaurantBinding.root

    }

    private fun getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, pixels: Int): Bitmap {
        val output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(output)

        val paint = Paint()
        val rect = Rect(0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
        val rectF = RectF(rect)

        val roundPx = pixels.toFloat()

        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
        paint.color = Color.BLACK
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint)

        paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint)

        return output
    }

    private fun drawableToBitmap(drawable: GradientDrawable, width: Int): Bitmap {
        val intrinsicWidth = drawable.intrinsicWidth
        val intrinsicHeight = drawable.intrinsicHeight
        val height = (width.toFloat() / intrinsicWidth * intrinsicHeight).toInt()

        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }
}

Issue which I am facing is when I click on the marker first time the images inside info window not loading and also images inside recycler view which again inside info window is also not loading.
When I click on the marker again at that time images are loading perfectly.
I want to load all the images in first click on the marker.
mMap!!.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
            if (mRegisteredVenuesHomeList!!.isNotEmpty()) {
                mRegisteredVenuesHomeList?.forEach { data ->
                    if (!data.venueSorting.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        data.venueSorting.forEach { venueSorting ->
                            if (venueSorting.name != null && Utils.isNotNull(venueSorting.name) && venueSorting.name.toString()
                                    .equals("popular", true)
                            ) {
                                val marker =
                                    if (venueSorting.count != null && venueSorting.count > 0) {
                                        addCustomMarker(3, data, venueSorting.count, true)
                                    } else {
                                        addCustomMarker(3, data)
                                    }
                                val markerData = MarkerData(marker, data)
                                markerDataList.add(markerData)
                            }

                            if (venueSorting.name != null && Utils.isNotNull(venueSorting.name) && venueSorting.name.toString()
                                    .equals("venue_on_spotlight", true)
                            ) {
                                val marker =
                                    if (venueSorting.count != null && venueSorting.count > 0) {
                                        addCustomMarker(1, data, venueSorting.count, true)
                                    } else {
                                        addCustomMarker(1, data)
                                    }
                                val markerData = MarkerData(marker, data)
                                markerDataList.add(markerData)
                            }

                            if (venueSorting.name != null && Utils.isNotNull(venueSorting.name) && venueSorting.name.toString()
                                    .equals("discountoffer", true)
                            ) {
                                val marker =
                                    if (venueSorting.count != null && venueSorting.count > 0) {
                                        addCustomMarker(2, data, venueSorting.count, true)
                                    } else {
                                        addCustomMarker(2, data)
                                    }
                                val markerData = MarkerData(marker, data)
                                markerDataList.add(markerData)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        val marker = addCustomMarker(0, data)
                        val markerData = MarkerData(marker, data)
                        markerDataList.add(markerData)
                    }
                }
            }
            mMap!!.setInfoWindowAdapter(object : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
                override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View? {
                    return null
                }

                override fun getInfoWindow(marker: Marker): View {
                    val markerData = markerDataList.find { it.marker == marker }
                    markerData?.let { markerDataUpdate ->
                        mInterestedTerritiersList!!.clear()
                        if (markerDataUpdate.data.territiers != null) {
                            mInterestedTerritiersList!!.addAll(
                                markerDataUpdate.data.territiers.take(
                                    5
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        preloadImages()
                        if (mInterestedTerritiersList != null) {
                            preloadTerritiersImages(mInterestedTerritiersList!!)
                        }
                        return CustomInfoWindowAdapter(
                            requireActivity(),
                            markerDataUpdate.data,
                            object : Click {
                                override fun onClick(position: Int, `object`: Any, value: String) {
                                    when (position) {
                                        1 -> {
                                            Utils.showLog(
                                                this@MapFragment.javaClass.simpleName, "1"
                                            )
                                        }

                                        2 -> {
                                            Utils.showLog(
                                                this@MapFragment.javaClass.simpleName, "2"
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }).getInfoWindow(marker)
                    }
                    return View(requireContext())
                }
            })

            mMap!!.setOnMarkerClickListener { clickedMarker ->
                val markerPosition = clickedMarker.position
                val point = mMap!!.projection.toScreenLocation(markerPosition)
                val offset = 300
                point.y -= offset
                val offsetPosition = mMap!!.projection.fromScreenLocation(point)
                mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(offsetPosition))
                clickedMarker.showInfoWindow()
                true
            }
            mMap!!.setOnInfoWindowClickListener { clickedMarker ->
                val markerData = markerDataList.find { it.marker == clickedMarker }
                markerData?.let { markerDataUpdate ->
                    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), RestaurantDetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constant.RESTAURANT_DETAIL, markerDataUpdate.data)
                    activityLauncher.launch(intent,
                        object : BetterActivityResult.OnActivityResult<ActivityResult> {
                            override fun onActivityResult(result: ActivityResult) {
                                if (result.resultCode == 101) {
                                    mMap?.let { _ ->
                                        openedInfoWindow?.let { marker ->
                                            marker.showInfoWindow()
                                            openedInfoWindow = null
                                        }
                                        currentLocationMarkerOptions?.let { options ->
                                            mMap!!.addMarker(options)
                                        }
                                        venuesAndOffers()
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        })
                    AnimUtils.enterAnimation(requireActivity())
                }
            }
        }

private fun preloadImages() {
        for (venue in mRegisteredVenuesHomeList!!) {
            venue.image?.let { imageUrl ->
                Glide.with(requireActivity()).load(imageUrl).preload()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun preloadTerritiersImages(territiersHome: List<HomeResponseModel.RegisteredVenuesDataHome.VenuesHome.TerritiersHome>) {
        for (territier in territiersHome) {
            // Assuming each territier has an image URL
            territier.profileImage!!.name?.let { imageUrl ->
                Glide.with(requireActivity()).load(imageUrl).preload()
            }
        }
    }

Please help me with this.
